# Grails- "Forked Grails VM exited with error", with many other errors

Tags: grails

I am following a simple Grails tutorial. When I start the program, it runs fine and the server starts for about 10 seconds, and then a mountain of errors comes up ending with "Forked Grails VM exited with error".

I gone through my code that I've edited and triple checked for typos, and check and update my JDK and Grails.

I am using Grails 2.4.5 and Oracle SQL Developer's JDK 1.7

The full list of errors can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/7gAtmZtY

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow, can you add the code you are currently working with to your question?

Comment: is your mysql running and/or is your connection url configured correct (DataSource.groovy)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the parameter dbCreate in your DataSource.groovy file.
You can easily find it in grails-app/conf in your project folder.

Find your specific database and change this parameter:

```
dbCreate = "create-drop"
```

Comment: Did you actually read the errors in the link he provided? `dbCreate` has nothing to do with this. `Connection refused: connect` implies that the connection information in `DataSource.groovy` isn't correct, or it might be a driver issue

Comment: Thanks, maybe you're right. All in all we need to have some pieces of code or further information.